# Is it possible to cast an Object to an exact type in Flow?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, flowtype

I'm wondering how one might go about casting an `Object` to a user defined exact type in Flow.  For example:

```
//@flow

type exactType = {|x : number|}

function test(a : Object) : exactType {
  if(typeof(a.x) === 'string'){
    return (a : exactType);
  }
  throw new Error('Incorrect type!')
}
```

Is it even possible to write such a function?  I.e. is it possible to convice the type checker that parameter `a` has only a single field named `x` with type `number`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no safe way to do this. However, you can always cast through `any` to circumvent the typechecker:

`return ((a: any): exactType);`

Ideally, you would refactor your code to avoid using `Object`, since it's an unsafe type. However, if that's not possible the best you can do is to carefully circumvent the typechecker like this.